# How to compute Haar average over the unitary group of a ratio of homogeneous polynomials?

Tags: haar-distribution, t-designs

I am interested in the following Haar average over the unitary group:

$\mathbb{E}_U\Big[\frac{tr(U^{\otimes p}|j\rangle\langle j|(U^\dagger)^{\otimes p}\rho \otimes \sigma ...)}{tr(U^{\otimes q}|j\rangle\langle j|(U^\dagger)^{\otimes q}\gamma \otimes \delta ...)}\Big]$,

where q < p, and the expectation is with respect to the Haar measure on the unitary group. The first thing to do is to write down the homogeneity.

$tr(U^{\otimes p}|j\rangle\langle j|(U^\dagger)^{\otimes p}\rho \otimes \sigma ...) \in$ Hom(p,p), and

$tr(U^{\otimes q}|j\rangle\langle j|(U^\dagger)^{\otimes q}\gamma \otimes \delta ...) \in $ Hom(q,q).

Does this mean that the integrand $\in$ Hom(p-q, p-q)? And so the integral over the Haar measure reduces to an average over a 'p-q' unitary design?

And how does one go about evaluating such integrals exactly? Or, establish upper bounds?

Comment: Typo of your formula? What is $\langle j$?

Comment: In short, no. For instance $x^k+y^k$ is a homogeneous polynomial of degree k, but $(x^3+y^3)/(x+y)$ is not a polynomial at all.

Comment: Sure, but what I have here is more like $x^3/x$, no?

Comment: Nope, it's a (multivariate) polynomial in all entries of the unitary. Hence if you consider unitaries beyond dimension $d=1$ you encounter the above situation

Comment: Nevertheless, how to compute the Haar-average of such fractional polynomials is an interesting question and I do not know the answer.

Comment: @MarkusHeinrich: Ah, yes. Thanks for the clarification!